npm warns about memory leak in a transitive dependency of bcrypt
Context
After installing bcrypt, I received several warnings about deprecated packages, but the first one is especially troubling:
$ npm install bcrypt
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. 
  Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce 
  async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.

$ npm ls inflight
└─┬ bcrypt@5.1.1
  └─┬ @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
    └─┬ rimraf@3.0.2
      └─┬ glob@7.2.3
        └── inflight@1.0.6

This warning about a potential memory leak leaves me concerned about whether bcrypt is safe for long-running applications in a production environment.
As you can see, the suggested fix per npm is to use lru-cache instead of inflight, which would require overriding rimraf by updating package.json with this:
{
...
  "overrides": {
    "rimraf": "^4.0.0"
  }
...
}

However, I'm hesitant to do that.
(Also, I can't update bcrypt@5.1.1 or @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 since these are the latest versions of each)
My questions are:

Do these deprecated dependencies pose a significant risk if I use bcrypt in production as-is?
If so, should I override this dependency the way I described above?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!


Additional Context:

Node.js version: v20.13.0
npm version: 10.5.2
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro (64-bit)


https://app.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-INFLIGHT-6095116 - it is likely, but I have not confirmed, that node-pre-gyp/rimraf/glob/inflight are used only in compiling the binary for bcrypt. snyk lists it as a local attack vector and it essentially is a memory leak risk that someone could crash your application if inflight was used within bcrypt, which it may not be except for compiling

I'd like to know if I should override or hope for changes since the inflight memory leak is still relatively new

This question is very relevant, voting to reopen.

@YesBarry, "very relevant" doesn't mean it should be reopened. It must be on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic], sufficiently detailed, etc. This question is quite opinion-based (not allowed) and asks multiple questions at once (not allowed). If you want it to be reopened, [edit] it to improve it.
